# ListView of recently opened files

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, button, richtextbox

I'm doing a text editor. How do I display a list of the last opened files in the `RichTextBox` in `ListView`? You can also click on the `ListView` string and open the file. Something like the history of opening files. Files are opened using `Button` (the code below).

```
private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Rich Text Format | *.rtf";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(ofd.FileName);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Add each filename you opened to a list and present that list with the listview.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i have done this was store all opened files within a settings string and store all recently opened files within that string with a delimiter like \n(i use this because you cant include it in a fie name so no errors are thrown).

For example, the settings string is stored like this

```
"C:\my file1\nC:\myFile2\nC:\my file 3"
```

And when adding a new file to the list

```
MyApp.Properties.Settings.recents = MyApp.Properties.Settings.recents + "\n" + ofd.FileName;
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

you then split that and use a forloop for each occurance to generate a new listview item like this

```
string[] recentFiles = MyApp.Properties.Settings.recents.split('\n');
foreach (string recentItem in recentFiles) { MyListView.add(recentItem); }
```